# Auto increment same values in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary:

```
{'someKey1': 1, 'someKey2': 1, 'someKey3': 1, 'someKey4': 3, 'someKey5': 4, 'someKey6': 4, 'someKey7': 2}
```

Output im trying to get is a dictionary with auto incremented values like so:

```
{'someKey1': 1, 'someKey2': 2, 'someKey3': 3, 'someKey4': 5, 'someKey5': 7, 'someKey6': 6, 'someKey7': 4}
```

Values in someKey1 - someKey3 don't matter as long as they are in 1-3, meaning someKey1 value can be 3 but 3 cannot repeat as value again in dict.

Basically first dict (yes it has to be a dict) contains order of keys but order can repeat thus i want to order is again with auto increment.

Further explanation:
I have a js object in frontend that contains column names from a table as keys, and in frontend user can pick which column should be in what order. Thus the "somekey" is actually column name, and number is where in postion should said column be placed.
The thing with same number for multiple keys is that user can split one column into multipe ones. Thus i dont care for order as long as they are in the same bracket e.g. someKey1-3  must be in postion 1-3 since they have value 1.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You can iterate over a dictionary with the `.items()` method, which may help you! `for key, value in mydict.items(): ...`

Comment: "contains order of keys": `dict`s are not ordered.

Comment: Are those keys just examples, or do you really have keys that end in numbers?

Comment: @fuenfundachtzig dictionaries are guaranteed to be insertion-ordered from Python 3.7+! [release highlights](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html)

Comment: @ti7 This is the step that i got stuck on, there is a lot of code before, insertion-ordered doesnt since the original dict order is made in react frontend and its not ordered there.

Comment: `{k:i for i,k in enumerate(ur_dict, 1)}`

Comment: @dawg this is not the output desired, please see expected output

Comment: How so? Whatever order your dict is in, it produces that same order with enumerated values. What is wrong then? If there is an issue, it is likely because the order of your dict is not what you assume...

Comment: I think OP wants the dict to be sorted by value first.

Comment: Except there's something special about the first 3 keys? It's not clear.

Comment: The first 3 have the same value, so apparently in that case the order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result indicates that the original values are used as an assignment order for new sequences. However, there is a factor of randomness to the assignment of keys that have the same initial value which I could not figure out from your explanations.  i.e. why are someKey1 and someKey2 receiving 1 and 2 while someKey5 and someKey6 get their new values (7 and 6) in descending order.

So the closest I could come to that result is this:

```
dict1 = {'someKey1': 1, 'someKey2': 1, 'someKey3': 1, 'someKey4': 3, 'someKey5': 4, 'someKey6': 4, 'someKey7': 2}


dict2 = { k:v for v,(k,_) in enumerate(sorted(dict1.items(),key=lambda kv:kv[1]),1) }
            

print(dict(sorted(dict2.items()))) # printed in key order to facilitate comparison

{'someKey1': 1, 'someKey2': 2, 'someKey3': 3, 'someKey4': 5, 'someKey5': 6, 'someKey6': 7, 'someKey7': 4}
```

It should be OK if you really don't care about the values given to keys that originally had the same value.

Comment: I have added more explanation, hope its more clear now.